# Using HTTPS for api routes ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, api, http, https

I have a asp.net application in which I used HTTP controllers (ApiController) as below

```
[Route("api/dashboard/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public DataTable getDashboardDetails(int ID)
{
}
```

Both my web application and controllers are within same application. We have modified our website from HTTP to HTTPS.

Now, when I try to call the above api route as
https://website.com/api/dashboard/123
it throws

> 404 - File or directory not found

Error

Please help to get the api called. Its working in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the ISS and visual studio configuration ?

Sometimes it need to be restarted to get this changes.

[image: ISS working hosts]

[image: Visual Studio Config]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried setting the application properties SSL enabled to true, still it displays same error as mentioned above